# Change a formula in excel based on a user input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to update multiple formulas based on a user input; for instance, I have vLookups that look for 4Q16 revenue, and I want it to search for 1Q17 revenue based on the user input on another sheet. Ideally, it would be based on what quarter we are in, but I've not had much luck getting the date functions to work in VBA. As an example, here is one of the vLookup formulas:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Local",RevByType,MATCH("Sum of 16Q4 Rev",RevByTypeHeader,0),0), "0.0")
```

Comment: What is your question? you make a couple of statements but no question.

Comment: Excel uses my input when I enter formulas.  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: You should add examples of user inputs and what effect they will have on the formula, e.g. will `Dave` need 4Q16, and `Alan` 1Q17?

Comment: How is this a `vba` or `excel-vba` question? I've edited your tags to reference `excel-formula` instead.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify - I want to update several formulas across multiple worksheets based on the value of a cell on a master worksheet. I have the first sheet used as a 'user input' sheet so I can sort by sales person, or customer, or end market, etc. I want to update formulas based on what the user puts in for 'quarter' and it will be in the form of YYQ# (using data validation to force this format). The formulas are hard-coded in VBA, which is why I added VBA. If I use the format mentioned by YowE3K, it works for in-sheet formulas, but other pages throw errors.

Comment: Clarification - I used named ranges and it appears to work for all non-VB formulas, however the ones hard-coded still don't update.

Answer (score 0):

With `16Q4` in A1, use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Local",RevByType,MATCH("Sum of " & A1 & "Rev",RevByTypeHeader,0),0), 0)
```

Type `17Q1` into A1 for different results. Alternately, use a data validation list of applicable quarters to avoid user mistypes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it based on which quarter we are in (in a "yyQq" format), rather than on user input, the following should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Local",RevByType,MATCH("Sum of " & TEXT(NOW(),"yy") & "Q" & INT((MONTH(NOW())+2)/3) & "Rev",RevByTypeHeader,0),0), "0.0")
```